# Jquery lock statement or equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery tooltips (tipsy plugin) to show validaton errors on my site. At the request of the client, I've modified the plugin to allow showing the tooltips on hover AND focus. However, when clicking a field with the mouse (rather than simply tabbing to it), both event handlers execute and there is a flicker on the tooltip because of both attempts to show it. What's the cleanest way to prevent multiple event handlers from executing in a scenario like this?

Comment: Determine if the tooltip is already visible, and if so, don't try to show it.